# using enum in switch/case

Tags: java

I have an entity that has an enum property:

```
// MyFile.java
public class MyFile {   
    private DownloadStatus downloadStatus;
    // other properties, setters and getters
}

// DownloadStatus.java
public enum DownloadStatus {
    NOT_DOWNLOADED(1),
    DOWNLOAD_IN_PROGRESS(2),
    DOWNLOADED(3);

    private int value;
    private DownloadStatus(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

I want to save this entity in database and retrieve it. The problem is that I save the int value in database and I get int value! I can not use switch like below:

```
MyFile file = new MyFile();
int downloadStatus = ...
switch(downloadStatus) {
    case NOT_DOWNLOADED:
    file.setDownloadStatus(NOT_DOWNLOADED);
    break;
    // ...
}
```

What should I do?

Comment: may be thats the worst case, but only solution what I can se is use a different getter via extending class which returns value as enum.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You could provide a static method in your enum:

```
public static DownloadStatus getStatusFromInt(int status) {
    //here return the appropriate enum constant
}
```

Then in your main code:

```
int downloadStatus = ...;
DowloadStatus status = DowloadStatus.getStatusFromInt(downloadStatus);
switch (status) {
    case DowloadStatus.NOT_DOWNLOADED:
       //etc.
}
```

The advantage of this vs. the ordinal approach, is that it will still work if your enum changes to something like:

```
public enum DownloadStatus {
    NOT_DOWNLOADED(1),
    DOWNLOAD_IN_PROGRESS(2),
    DOWNLOADED(4);           /// Ooops, database changed, it is not 3 any more
}
```

Note that the initial implementation of the `getStatusFromInt` might use the ordinal property, but that implementation detail is now enclosed in the enum class.

Answer (score 12):

Every Java enum has an ordinal which is automatically assigned, so you don't need to manually specify the int (but be aware that ordinals start from 0, not 1).

Then, to get your enum from the ordinal, you can do:

```
int downloadStatus = ...
DownloadStatus ds = DownloadStatus.values()[downloadStatus];
```

... then you can do your switch using the enum ...

```
switch (ds)
{
  case NOT_DOWNLOADED:
  ...
}
```

Comment: "..., so you don't need to manually specify the int..." <--- This is NOT true when you need to communicate with other (third party) software or machines that have fixed integers for a certain interface (e.g. message type)!

Comment: @user504342: The point of this answer is that an enum already contains an ordinal, and so _if your use case allows you to rely on that_, you can without needing to do anything more. If you can't use the ordinal because you have to conform to some existing scheme, then [assylias' answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14154869/1212960) covers this.

Comment: \@GregKopff: sorry to disagree. According to Joshua Bloch book Effective Java (2nd ed.) you should NOT rely on ordinal values. See item 31 which clearly states: "Never derive a value associated with an enum from its ordinal; store it in an instance field instead". The book explains in detail why that is.