# Switching on values of custom enum values

Tags: java, enums

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [using enum in switch/case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14154784/using-enum-in-switch-case)

Given enum

```
public enum ExitCodes {

    DESPITE_MULTIPLE_ATTEMPTS_CONNECTION_TO_SERVER_FAILED(-1),
    PROGRAM_FINISHED_SUCCESSFULLY(0),
    // ... more stuff

    private final int id;

    ExitCodes(final int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

As part of another class, i'd like to

```
switch (exitCode) {
    case ExitCodes.PROGRAM_FINISHED_SUCCESSFULLY.getValue():
       // do stuff
```

Fails with `Constant expression required`

Why is this? As i understand it, numeric value assigned to id in `ExitCodes` is Constant (`final`)

How can this be corrected please?

Comment: How is a method call a constant?  The compiler doesn't "know" that `getValue()` simply returns the `id`.

Comment: Any way to go around this?

Comment: @mellamokb Got to get the value, else it's incompatible types. `int` vs `ExitCodes`

Comment: @Jam: Sorry I'm thinking in C#, which is less restrictive on converting `int` to `Enum`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A non-map approach would be to "walk" through the enum entries like so in `ExitCodes`:

```
public static ExitCodes getByID(int id) {
   for (final ExitCodes element : EnumSet.allOf(ExitCodes.class)) {
    if (element.id == id) {
      return element;
    }
   }

   throw new IllegalArgumentException("Can't find " + id);
}
```

Then to lookup you could do:

```
switch (ExitCodes.getByID(exitCode)) {
    case PROGRAM_FINSHED_SUCCESSFULLY:
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a Map of Exit codes to `ExitCode` enum values.  Then you can do

```
switch(ExitCode.lookup(exitCode)) {
    case PROGRAM_FINSHED_SUCCESSFULLY:
```

Comment: I was looking for a way to avoid map with an enum, but yes, i see your point

Comment: If numbers are consecutive you can base it off the ordinal property.

Answer (score 1):

We have a similar pattern at my work.

Change your enum class to add a reverse lookup map:

```
public enum ExitCodes {

    // All the same until here
    private static HashMap<Integer, ExitCodes> valueToExitCodeMap = null;

    public static ExitCodes getEnumByValue(int value)
    {
        if(valueToExitCodeMap == null)
        {
            valueToExitCodeMap = new HashMap<Integer, ExitCodes>();
            for(ExitCodes code : values())
            {
                valueToExitCodeMap.put(new Integer(code.id), code);
            }
        }
        return valueToExitCodeMap.get(new Integer(value));
    }
}
```

Then change this:

```
switch (ExitCodes.getEnumByValue(exitCode)) {
case PROGRAM_FINISHED_SUCCESSFULLY:
   // do stuff
```

Comment: When following this approach, i get `An enum switch case musts be unqualified name of the enumeration constant`